# I am new at Django and kept being stuck at the ERROR 404 (Page Not Found)

Tags: django, web, backend

Using the URLconf defined in firstProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:  index/ [name='main-view'] admin/ The empty path didn’t match any of these.

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include,path
    from firstApp import views
    urlpatterns = [
        path('index/',views.index, name = 'main-view'),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Comment: Replace `'index/'` with `''`? You don't have a url pattern for the empty path which is why you get the 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a url pattern for the empty route, hence, you are getting `ERROR 404`.
Change

```
path('index/',views.index, name = 'main-view'),
```

to

```
path('',views.index, name = 'main-view'),
```

in your `urlpatterns` list and your index view defined in your views.py will run.